# gnu ld: symbol remains undefined, even when it is defined

Tags: gcc, undefined, ld

Trying to link a program which (for unknown reasons) generates a reference to "xmemdup".

I found the source code for xmemdup.c, and compiled it, and included the .o file in the link, but ld still claims it is undefined.

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -O2 -pipe -DBINDIR=\"/usr/bin\"   -c -o rsh.o rsh.c
```

This worked, generating rsh.o

```
$ ll rsh.o ../publib-0.40/alloc/xmemdup.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 perryh perryh  2344 Dec 29 22:25 ../publib-0.40/alloc/xmemdup.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 perryh perryh 68656 Dec 30 00:47 rsh.o
```

Proves that the .o files I am about to pass to the linker do exist.  BTW xmemdup.o is an object file, not a library, so it should get included unconditionally even if it were not needed to resolve a reference.

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -O2 -pipe -DBINDIR=\"/usr/bin\" -o rsh rsh.o ../publib-0.40/alloc/xmemdup.o
/usr/bin/ld: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/ld: undefined symbol: xmemdup
collect2: error: ld returned 127 exit status
```

and yet the linker can't see the definition of xmemdup in xmemdup.o

Comment: `nm` is your friend.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `/usr/bin/ld` is not executable due to a missing symbol. Try `ldd -r /usr/bin/ld`.

Comment: ldd -r confirms amonakov's suspicion that it is /usr/bin/ld itself that contains the reference to xmemdup, which explains why supplying xmemdup as input to the linker does not help.  The question remains, how to fix it?  xmemdup is defined in libgettextlib.so, which is in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu along with the other shared libs.  How do I get the dynamic linker to find it when collect2 is trying to exec /usr/bin/ld?